# joomla registration form validation

Tags: joomla

I am setting up a joomla 1.5 and using login module.Mostly done. One major issue pending is that the "new user registration" page does not show any error message. When I submit the form with no or wrong entries, the pages just stays like that. No refreshing of page, no error message shown. I am getting other types of error messages (meaning the error mechanism works for other pages). Anyone had a similar issue for the registration page before? Any recommended fix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

update your joomla version or replace your joomla 1.5 core validation.js file with new joomla version validation.js

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason in this while googling. I noticed that module com_virtuemart was not showing up in the module list under module manager. The login form and registration forms were showing up from Joomla module. I re-installed the com_virtuemart module and unpublished the login form in Joomla. That cleared my issue.

Link :http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2516776